# strange issue/bug, html5 nav element effecting absolute positioning of another item

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate

Ok got this strange issue where i have a absolute positioned div with inside a header.  Then there's a nav tag with a margin and for some the absolute positioned div instead of sitting top left of header it positioned where the nav starts. So if the nav has 100px top margin the div starts 100px down.

But the strange thing is if I apply a border to the header the absolute positioned div acts as how i would expect.
I'm using html5 boilerplate styles, this i suppose could be the issue.

It's easier to explain if you view an example.  The below links are stripped down version and have identical mark up apart from one where the header has a border and the other it doesn't.

Example with the problem:
http://bennyb.co.uk/test/no-border.html

Example with the issue fixed when the border is applied
http://bennyb.co.uk/test/border.html

Thanks

B

EDIT:
Ok thought this was actually just related to nav but seems it's the same if a div

Comment: Ok the only thing i managed to get to work without effecting anything else was adding the clearfix to it.

Answer (score 2):

Apply

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the header.

Comment: Thanks Caio, thats does the trick.  The question now is why does it behave this way. Why would having a border change it and if it's a div as apposed to the nav tag the issue isn't there.

Comment: My bit about it only being related to the nav is wrong, it does also effect div's.

Comment: Ok snag with using overflow hidden.  If you have a drop down menu this will get cut off.  Any other solutions?